# Using a 2-column mapping dataframe in R to change values in main dataframe

Tags: r

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I have a feeling it has been asked, but I will provide a good example to help with understanding this. First the demo dataframes:

```
> map_df = data.frame(name = c('nick', 'mike', 'joe', 'tom'), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> main_df = data.frame(P1 = c('nick', 'mike', 'nick', 'mike', 'nick', 'mike', 'joe', 'tom'),
                     P2 = c('joe', 'tom', 'joe', 'tom', 'joe', 'tom', 'nick', 'mike'), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> map_df
  name id
1 nick  1
2 mike  2
3  joe  3
4  tom  4

> main_df
    P1   P2
1 nick  joe
2 mike  tom
3 nick  joe
4 mike  tom
5 nick  joe
6 mike  tom
7  joe nick
8  tom mike
```

With the data above, my question / desired output is simple. I want to replace all values in main_df, with the associated id. I'd like the following output dataframe:

```
> output_df
    P1   P2
1    1    3
2    2    4
3    1    3
4    2    4 
5    1    3
6    2    4
7    3    1
8    4    2
```

Thanks in advance for the help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `match`.  Loop over the columns with `lapply`, `match` with 'name' column of 'map_df' and use the numeric index to change the values to the corresponding 'id' in 'map_df', assign the output to 'main_df'

```
main_df[] <- lapply(main_df, function(x) map_df$id[match(x, map_df$name)])
```

---

Or convert it to a `matrix` and match it

```
main_df[] <- setNames(map_df$id, map_df$name)[as.matrix(main_df)]
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect, use of the match function is a good fit here

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use your map_df as a look-up table.

```
rownames(map_df) = map_df$name
main_df$P1 = map_df[main_df$P1, "id"]
main_df$P2 = map_df[main_df$P2, "id"]
```